# Field value becomes null in inherited class

Tags: java, spring-boot, inheritance, nullpointerexception

Basically I have a bean class, lets say Emp

```
class Emp{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public Emp(int id, String name){
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
    }
// Setters and Getters
}
```

There is another class which contains an Emp reference

```
class MyClass{
    protected Emp emp;
    protected ModelAndView mav;

    protected ModelAndView getView(int id, String name){
        emp = new Emp(id,name);
        mav = new ModelAndView("my-view"); // JSP Page
        mav.addObject("emp",emp);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Controller 1 returns a view and sets the value of **emp** variable inside MyClass

```
@Controller
class Controller1 extends MyClass{

    @RequestMapping("/req1")
    public ModelAndView view1(){
        return getView(1,"John");
    }
}
```

Ideally, since the value of **emp** has been set, it should display "John" in the console. However when I make a call through my second controller, I get a NullPointerException

```
@Controller
class Controller2 extends MyClass{

    @RequestMapping("/req2")
    public ModelAndView view2(){
        System.out.println(emp.getName()); // -> NullPointerException 
        return mav;
    }
}
```

What could be the possible reason behind such an issue?

Comment: in controller2 never initialized emp of MyClass, hence NPE, controller1 doesnt effect on here

Comment: @benjaminc can you please explain a little better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cntroller1 and controller2 have no link and when you initialize emp in controller1 and call controller2, it will be 2 different requests. So that is why you are getting null pointer excpetion.

You need to have emp as static to persist it's value.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different controllers, each extending MyClass. Each of those controllers have their own instance of Emp. Therefore, although you already invoked '/req1' and initialized the value of Emp in Controller1, the Emp value in Controller2 is still uninitialized (hence the NPE when you try to invoke something on it).